# Unable to start solr aspect of DSE search

Tags: java, php, solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am unable to start the solr aspect of DSE search and i get the following exception message when i execute, when i execute bin/dse cassandra start the cassandra service is started but not solr, does anyone have any guidance to offer me i know i have missed something:

bin/dse cassandra -s

message:

```
Cannot start node if snitch's data center (Solr) differs from previous data center (Cassandra). Please fix the snitch configuration, decommission and rebootstrap this node or use the flag -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true.
at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:629) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.12.1046.jar:2.1.12.1046]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:290) [cassandra-all-2.1.12.1046.jar:2.1.12.1046]
at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:329) [dse-4.7.7.jar:4.7.7]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:564) [cassandra-all-2.1.12.1046.jar:2.1.12.1046]
at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:75) [dse-4.7.7.jar:4.7.7]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of DataStax Enterprise do not allow you to change the workload of an existing node with existing data. In order to start this node, either remove all data in the data folder (effectively, start clean) or use the `-Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true` flag (as it says in the error).

Comment: I have added the ignore flag but nothing has happened which data folder are you referring to?

Comment: The data folder pointed to by the ```data_file_directories``` option in your cassandra.yaml. If this isn't set then it defaults to $CASSANDRA_HOME/data/data

Comment: it is set so should i remove all three folders as there is a dse_system folder in there as well

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the data as a service

Remove all data from a package installation.

Procedure

To clear the data from the default directories:

After stopping the service, run the following command:

$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/*